# OPENCV: I want to draw basic shapes in a loop removing older shapes each time a new shape is drawn

Tags: c, opencv

I have taken code from shape.c given in opencv library and modified a little bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<3 ;i++)
   { 
    /* create an image */
    IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(200, 100), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

    /* draw a green line */
    cvLine(img,                         /* the dest image */
           cvPoint(10 +i*10, 10),             /* start point */
           cvPoint(150, 80),            /* end point */
           cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0),      /* the color; green */
           1, 8, 0);                    /* thickness, line type, shift */

    /* draw a blue box */
    cvRectangle(img,                    /* the dest image */
                cvPoint(20, 15+i*10),        /* top left point */
                cvPoint(100, 70),       /* bottom right point */
                cvScalar(255, 0, 0, 0), /* the color; blue */
                1, 8, 0);               /* thickness, line type, shift */

    /* draw a red circle */
    cvCircle(img,                       /* the dest image */
             cvPoint(110, 60), 35+i*10,      /* center point and radius */
             cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0),    /* the color; red */
             1, 8, 0);                  /* thickness, line type, shift */

    /* display the image */
    cvNamedWindow("img", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("img", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvDestroyWindow("img");
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    }     
    return 0;
}
```

I want that whenever i increments, old figures should be removed and only new figures should be drawn.But what i am getting is, along with new figures old figures are also present.Can you help me please?.

Comment: Probably not your problem, but you're opening a new window each time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way

1. Initialize a background image
2. Draw foreground shape on a newly cloned background image
3. Draw another shape on a cloned background image
4. Display them one by one

Answer (score 1):

When you create a (blank) image, the only way to be sure *imageData* is clean is to do it yourself by setting a solid color. After `cvCreateImage()` call `cvSet()`.

```
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(200, 100), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3); 
cvSet(img, CV_RGB(0, 0, 0));
```

You can improve the performance of your application if the take out window creation/destruction out of the loop.  There's no need to create a new window for every new image:

```
int i = 0;
cvNamedWindow("img", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
for(i=0;i<3 ;i++)
{
    // code
}
cvDestroyWindow("img");
```